# Could not resolve type of column \"id\" of class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I encounter an this error with Doctrine and Symfony2:

> Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "ST\UserBundle\Entity\User"

**Statistic**

```
class Statistique
{
    // ...

    // @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ST\UserBundle\Entity\User")
    // @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPro", referencedColumnName="id")
    private $user;
}
```

---

## EDIT #1:

**User**

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

// @ORM\Table(name="tiers_prov3")
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="TIE_ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    protected $id;

    // ...
}
```

I can't figure it out.

Comment: is `$id` the property name of your User Entity?

Comment: Oh yes I didn't say that. But yes it is.

Comment: Try to delete  `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPro", referencedColumnName="id")` and php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: Normaly the ORM\GeneratedValue would be (strategy="AUTO"). If you dont want to autoincrement userId's you will have to set the unique id yourself.

Comment: Don't focus on the UserBundle, I generate the uniqid fine :) And @fcpauldiaz I really want to keep my `idPro` column (for unity reason) and the unique thing that will do is to change it by `user_id` . But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your column name for $id property in User class is "TIE_ID". So try to use this name instead of id in your Statistic class :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ST\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPro", referencedColumnName="TIE_ID") <== here
 */
private $user;
```

In Doctrine annotations, columns names - like in `@ORM\Column(name="x"...)` and `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="y", referencedColumnName="x" ...)` - are real database column names.

Comment: You teached me something about doctrine ! I didn't know that the referencedColumnName needs the db column name. Thank you, It still some problems with the serialization but it's another thread.